# How can I change global type information format in Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson for json serialization/deserialization.

I am using global configuration for type information to support polymorphism.

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

It is including type information as a wrapped array for every objects, which is fine to me.

Only thing is that I want to change the format of included information, want to use key:value pair like mentioned below.

```
{@type:com.....xyz}
```

where @type is key and XYZ is class name, similar like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "as property" inclusion for default typing, because not all values are of Object type (List, arrays, scalar values). But you can use `@JsonTypeInfo` to specify that style for POJOs you do have; and you should be able to mix this with default typing, such that anything for which properties won't work will use default typing.

Comment: Yes but my limitation is I do not want to use class level annotation and format and default type information is not what I need , so what else can I do, if you can suggest me best alternative that it will be very heplful to me.